# SQL to find start and end date for an ID

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with ID, start_date and end_date columns.

Table:

```
ID    start_date    end_date
1     01/01/2017    01/01/2018
1     01/01/2018    01/01/2019
1     01/01/2019    01/01/2020
2     01/01/2016    01/01/2017
2     01/01/2017    01/01/2018
2     01/01/2019    01/01/2020
```

I want to write a query to get the following output:

Output:

```
ID    start_date    end_date
1     01/01/2017    01/01/2020
2     01/01/2016    01/01/2018
2     01/01/2019    01/01/2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a cumulative sum to solve this variation of the gaps-and-island problem:

```
select 
    id,
    min(start_date) start_date,
    max(end_date) end_date
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(case when start_date = lag_end_date then 0 else 1 end) 
            over(partition by id order by start_date) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            lag(end_date) over(partition by id order by start_date) lag_end_date
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by id, grp
order by id, grp
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=36bb99da69ff71335ca292a66aec4cd6)**:

```
ID | START_DATE | END_DATE  
-: | :--------- | :---------
 1 | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2020
 2 | 01/01/2016 | 01/01/2018
 2 | 01/01/2019 | 01/01/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of gaps and islands.

My recommendation in this case is to use a cumulative max to see if there are any overlaps with preceding rows and use that to determine where an "island" starts.  Then, use a cumulative sum to define the islands and aggregation:

```
select id, min(start_date), max(end_date
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date >= start_date then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by start_date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_date) over (partition by id
                                       order by start_date
                                       rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                      ) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by id, grp;
```

Comment: @PrasannaKumar . . . This was posted four minutes before GMB's very similar solution.  Can you explain why you preferred that solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
     Select id, Min(startdate), Max(case 
          when 
           lag(enddate) 
         over
    (partition by id order by id) =startdate
       then 
       Enddate end) from table group by
       id;
```